# Specific radio buttons - the most simple way to set different styles for first/last buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, radio-button, xml-drawable

I would like to achieve this specific type of radio buttons in my layout:

[image]

= different graphics for the first item, middle ones, and last one, which have different rounded corners. I can imagine doing this with different styles for the 3 types of buttons (using custom styles, stateful drawables).

I'm implementing this using custom toggle buttons. I would like to take advantage of drawable selector for using different drawables for the first and the last items, so I use:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_first="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_left_act"/> 

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_last="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_right_act"/> 

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_middle_act"/> 

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_first="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_left_inact"/> 

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_last="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_right_inact"/> 

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_middle_inact"/> 

</selector>
```

But now I have a problem, that states `state_first`, `state_last` are not set automatically in my `LinearLayout`, so I have to set them manually every time the buttons are clicked. Is there some way, some layout, where these states are set automatically? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found nothing special, so here is a "default" solution, with custom toggle buttons. Here are 3 different styles (put to `styles.xml`) for first, middle ones and last buttons:

```
<!-- Toggle button styles -->

<style name="CustomToggle">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">9dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">9dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>            

<style name="FirstToggle" parent="@style/CustomToggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_first</item>
</style>            

<style name="MiddleToggle" parent="@style/CustomToggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_middle</item>
</style>            

<style name="LastToggle" parent="@style/CustomToggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_last</item>
</style>
```

And a short code for activity handling the events of toggle buttons, so only 1 button is checked in the same time, and checked button is disabled:

```
public class AktivityActivity extends Activity 
{
    ArrayList<ToggleButton> toggle_buttons;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aktivity);

        initToggleButtons();
    }

    private void initToggleButtons() 
    {
        toggle_buttons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();
        toggle_buttons.add((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_1));
        toggle_buttons.add((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_2));
        toggle_buttons.add((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_3));

        // Listen on all toggle buttons
        for (ToggleButton toggle_button : toggle_buttons)
            toggle_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(check_listener);

        // Check first toggle button
        updateToggleButtons(toggle_buttons.get(0));
    }

    // Only one toggle can be checked, and checked button must be disabled
    private void updateToggleButtons(ToggleButton checked_button)
    {
        for (ToggleButton toggle_button : toggle_buttons)
        {
            toggle_button.setChecked(toggle_button == checked_button);
            toggle_button.setEnabled(toggle_button != checked_button);
        }
    }

    // Toggle buttons change listener
    OnCheckedChangeListener check_listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
                updateToggleButtons((ToggleButton) buttonView);
        }
    };
}
```

Maybe it can be usefull for somebody...

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Wordpress Android project. They use a "ToggleButton" that gives similar functionality. For the .xml look [here](https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/res/layout/edit.xml). To download the complete source go [here](http://android.wordpress.org/development/).

It wont be the same as what you want, as they just have toggle buttons, but that can most likely be adapted for your needed style of radio buttons (if it's not already built in).

The Wordpress Android project helped me learn a lot. Everything from theming, custom buttons, custom layouts, toggle buttons, xmlrpc, and more.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm checking these codes right now, but I'm not sure, if I see the thing that is similar to my case. I think they use only one style of toggle button there. But I agree there is much nice work with styles and if there will be no good "ready-solution" I will have to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The simplest way I found for doing this is:

1) Extend RadioButton class as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class RoundedButton extends RadioButton {

    private static final int[] STATE_ONLY_ONE = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.state_first,
            android.R.attr.state_last,
    };

    private static final int[] STATE_FIRST = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.state_first
    };

    private static final int[] STATE_LAST = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.state_last
    };

    public RoundedButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
        }

        final int size = parent.getChildCount();
        final boolean isFirst = (parent.getChildAt(0) == this);
        final boolean isLast = (parent.getChildAt(size-1) == this);

        int[] states = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
        if (isFirst && isLast) {
            mergeDrawableStates(states, STATE_ONLY_ONE);
        } else if (isFirst) {
            mergeDrawableStates(states, STATE_FIRST);
        } else if (isLast) {
            mergeDrawableStates(states, STATE_LAST);
        }

        return states;
    }

}
```

2) Create One XML file in "res/drawable/rbtn_selector.xml" add below XML code for Radio Button background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- First Checked -->
    <item android:state_first="true" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_selected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_selected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />-->
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_selected" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- First Unchecked -->
    <item android:state_first="true" android:state_checked="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple"/>-->
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/radio_button_radius"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_unselected" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Last Checked -->
    <item android:state_last="true" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_selected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_selected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />-->
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/radio_button_radius" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/radio_button_radius"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_selected" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Last Unchecked -->
    <item android:state_last="true" android:state_checked="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>-->
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/radio_button_radius" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/radio_button_radius"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_unselected" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <!-- Default Checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_selected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_selected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_selected" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Default Unchecked -->
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_start"
                android:endColor="@color/radio_button_unselected_end"
                android:type="linear" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/radio_button_border" android:color="@color/radio_button_border_unselected" />
            <!--<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

3) Create One XML file in "res/drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector.xml" add below XML code for Radio Buttons Text selector color.(Text Color Selector xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/radio_text_selected"/>
    <item android:color="@color/radio_text_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

4) Set your style to the button:

4.1) Programmatically add some RoundedButton to an exixsting RadioGroup:

```
RoundedButton newRadioButton = new RoundedButton(this.getActivity());

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    newRadioButton.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rbtn_selector));
} else {
    newRadioButton.setBackground(this.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rbtn_selector));
}
newRadioButton.setTextColor(this.getActivity().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.rbtn_textcolor_selector));
```

4.2) Xml:

```
<RoundedButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_id_1"
    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />
```

5) Choose your own colors and dimensions the one I used in the example are:

```
<color name="radio_text_selected">#FFF</color>
<color name="radio_text_unselected">#222</color>

<color name="radio_button_selected_start">#5393c5</color>
<color name="radio_button_selected_end">#6facd5</color>

<color name="radio_button_unselected_start">#f9f9f9</color>
<color name="radio_button_unselected_end">#eee</color>

<color name="radio_button_border_selected">#2373a5</color>
<color name="radio_button_border_unselected">#aaa</color>
```

and:

```
<dimen name="radio_button_radius">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="radio_button_border">0.7dp</dimen>
```